# Adding svg as a pseudoelement

Tags: css, svg, pseudo-element

I am trying to place an svg as a pseudoelement after two different divs.
My code is

```
    .mydiv:after{
           content: url("data:image/svg+xml;charset=UTF-8, <svg xmlns='http://www.w3.org/2000/svg' viewBox='0 0 64 64' width='2em' height='1.5em' ><path d='M32,43.71a3,3,0,0,1-2.12-.88L12.17,25.12a2,2,0,0,1,0-2.83l1.42-1.41a2,2,0,0,1,2.82,0L32,36.47,47.59,20.88a2,2,0,0,1,2.82,0l1.42,1.41a2,2,0,0,1,0,2.83L34.12,42.83A3,3,0,0,1,32,43.71Z'/></svg>");
           position:relative;
    }
```

and the HTML

```
    <h4><div class="mydiv">...</div></h4>
    <small><div class="mydiv">...</div></small>
```

My problem is that the h4 and the small have different sizes - thus, the svg needs to be sized and aligned differently. How can I change the code so that the svg always adapts to whatever is in front of it?

Comment: can you add a screenshot of how looks on your screen?

Comment: https://postimg.cc/WD6j6zrL

Answer (score 1):

```
.mydiv:after{
       content:"";
       display:inline-block;
       width:20px;
       height:20px;
       background-image:url("data:image/svg+xml;charset=UTF-8, <svg xmlns='http://www.w3.org/2000/svg' viewBox='0 0 64 64' width='2em' height='1.5em' ><path d='M32,43.71a3,3,0,0,1-2.12-.88L12.17,25.12a2,2,0,0,1,0-2.83l1.42-1.41a2,2,0,0,1,2.82,0L32,36.47,47.59,20.88a2,2,0,0,1,2.82,0l1.42,1.41a2,2,0,0,1,0,2.83L34.12,42.83A3,3,0,0,1,32,43.71Z'/></svg>");
       background-size:contain;
       background-position:bottom center;
       background-repeat:no-repeat;
}
```

Comment: This does not work...it makes the svgs still the same size for both h4 and small.

Comment: I think it's a good ansver, Use em instead of px for the width and height

Comment: change the height relatively to your font-size, for example if its h1, add `h1 > .mydiv:after{height:1.5rem;}` or `small > .mydiv:after{ height:1rem; }`